# Trouble passing variable to puppeteer's page.$eval

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to pass an object with login information to puppeteers `page.$eval` but the object is undefined in the function context. Here is my snippet:

```
const loginData = {
    user: "user@mail.com",
    password: "mypassword"
};

await page.$eval("input[type='email']", el => {
    el.value = loginData.user
}, loginData);
await page.$eval("input[type='password']", el => {
    el.value = loginData.password
}, loginData);
```

But it works if I pass string literal instead of `loginData.user` and `loginData.password`
I don’t understand the instructions: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args on how to properly pass additional arguments.

Alternatively, `page.evaluate` works fine:

```
    await page.evaluate((loginData) => {
        document.querySelector("input[type='email']").value = loginData.user;
    },loginData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistakenly wrong in understanding the `page.$eval` method in your code.

> const searchValue = await page.$eval('#search', el => el.value);

Line above is extracting the value of a selector with id `search`, **and not the opposite way** - write to `#search` input.

---

So to make your code passing an argument to be written in an input element selector, your code should be like this.

```
await page.type('input[type="email"]', loginData.user, {delay: 100}); // Types slower, like a user
await page.type('input[type="password"]', loginData.password, {delay: 10}); // Types faster, just like robot
```

Or, alternatively, if you want to use `await page.evaluate`

```
await page.evaluate((loginData) => {
    document.querySelector("input[type='email']").value = loginData.user;
    document.querySelector("input[type='password']").value = loginData.password;
},loginData);
```